# WPF - which panel type to use for such a layout?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

in the image below you see two orange rectangles. They represent the main containers. Currently I am using Wrap-Panels for them. Their content (Grids) is represented by the purple rectangles.

The top orange rectangles (Wrap Panel) is what I currently have.
The bottom orange rectangle (WrapPanel) represents what I would like.

The WrapPanel seems to place only one item per column per row.
Is there any way to have the Wrap Panel stack multiple items within a column?

The Purple controls (Grids) are generated at runtime. There can be a lot of them.
With the current layout there is a lot of wasted space.

I am looking to arrange the Grids in the most compact way possible. This can be thought of as a 2d rectangle placement optimization problem (Nesting).

Are there any Containers (can be third party) that provide such functionality?

Thank you!

[image: WPF Panel question]

Comment: Looks exactly like a WrapPanel with vertical Orientation.

Comment: @Clemens what I have seen with the WrapPanel is the last Grid would be shown on a new row, if the content needs to be wraped. So it would be placed below the largest Grid on the left. If no wrapping is necessary the Grids are just placed besides each other but never stacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Orientation` of the WrapPanel to `Vertical`:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="100" Width="300" Background="Orange">
    <Rectangle Margin="5" Width="80" Height="60" Fill="Purple"/>
    <Rectangle Margin="5" Width="80" Height="50" Fill="Purple"/>
    <Rectangle Margin="5" Width="80" Height="40" Fill="Purple"/>
    <Rectangle Margin="5" Width="80" Height="30" Fill="Purple"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had the Orientation set to horizontal. I had been looking at the wrong WrapPanel. Complex UI... :-)